# Is there a way to multiply the values in two columns while grouping by values in third column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to avoid using a loop while calculating the mean of the weighted grades in each of these courses.

I just can't wrap my head around what to do. I assume I can use groupby and perform the appropriate calcualtions?

This is the dataframe:

```
data = 

mark  weight  course_id
78      10          1
87      40          1
15      50          1
78      90          3
40      10          3
```

This is the desired result:

```
result=

course_id  course_average
1            50.1
3            74.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers don't always add up to 100 for each group, then you can calculate the proportion of `weight` for each row of each group and multiply by `mark`.

```
(data.assign(wa = data['mark'] * data['weight'] / 
             data.groupby('course_id')['weight'].transform('sum'))
     .groupby('course_id')['wa'].sum())
Out[1]: 
course_id
1    50.1
3    74.2
Name: wa, dtype: float64
```

If the weights do add up to 100 for each group, then the calculation is easier:

```
data.assign(wa = data['mark'] * data['weight'] / 100).groupby('course_id')['wa'].sum()

Out[2]: 
course_id
1    50.1
3    74.2
Name: wa, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, the data is guaranteed to add up to 100.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to go about it :

```
(df.assign(course_average=df.mark * df.weight)
   .groupby("course_id")
   .pipe(lambda x: x.course_average.sum().div(x.weight.sum()))
   .reset_index(name="course_average"))


    course_id   course_average
0      1         50.1
1      3         74.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple 1 liner using `groupby` and `lambda` for weighted average as follows -

```
df.groupby(['course_id']).apply(lambda x: sum(x['mark']*x['weight'])/sum(x['weight']))
```

```
course_id
1    50.1
3    74.2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would it be more performant to avoid apply and use assign like David Erickson did? I think both solutions here will create a new a dataframe in memory anyways.